# mysql multiple column order

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting

I'm using mysql database to store companies in the same city. And I'm fetching them by using below query. However it doesnt sort the result as I want it to be.
I want the resulting companies to be ordered like this: First priority is the companies which distances are lower than **6 KM** and those companies must be the ordered by  the **FIELD(sectorid,....)** parameter , second priority is the companies which distances are greater than 6KM and those companies must be ordered in the same way (with FIELD parameter)

But we couldnt find any solution to our problem. I'm showing the correct results and our query in below. I would be glad if someone points me to right direction

**Example Result Must be Something Like This:**

```
Company Name:      Distance:        SectorID:
CompanyA              3               10
CompanyB              2               11
CompanyC              4               13
CompanyX              8               10
CompanyY              7               11
CompanyZ              9               13
```

**Our Current Query:**

```
SELECT companies.id,
       companies.name,
       companies.summary,
       companies.ratingScore,
       companies.companyLogo,
       companies.sectorId,
       companies.lattitude,
       companies.longitude,
       companies.address,
       company_photos.photoUrl,

  (SELECT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
      FROM favorites
      WHERE favorites.companyId = companies.id
        AND userId = 109)) AS favorited,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ratings
   WHERE companies.id = ratings.companyId
     AND ratings.isReviewed = 1) AS comments,
       (ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(41.212641))*SIN(RADIANS(lattitude))+COS(RADIANS(41.212641))*COS(RADIANS(lattitude))*COS(RADIANS(longitude)-RADIANS(29.020058))) *6371) AS distance
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN company_photos ON company_photos.companyId = companies.id
AND company_photos.photoOrder = 0
WHERE companies.isActivated = 1
  AND companies.isReviewed = 1
  AND companies.isCustomer = 1
  AND companies.isBlocked = 0
ORDER BY FIELD (sectorId, 10, 11, 13, 7, 12, 2, 15, 17), distance
```

**The Result I'm Getting Is:**

```
Company Name:      Distance:        SectorID:
CompanyA              3               10
CompanyX              8               10
CompanyB              2               11
CompanyY              7               11
CompanyC              4               13
CompanyZ              9               13
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: UNION ALL, using the 6KM less than, greater than rule.

Comment: Also you need a comma in your ORDER BY. It should read ORDER BY FIELD (sectorId, 10, 11, 13, 7, 12, 2, 15, 17), distance

Comment: I've updated the first post for showing the result I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

```
order by case when distance<6 then 1 else 2 end, --sorts distance < 6 first and then distance > 6
sectorid --with in each group specified above sorting is on sectorid
```

Comment: case when caluse doesnt work the way I want. Because in both cases I want the same ordering with sectorid only difference is First I want to show the nearest companies with the same sectoring order then I want to show the far companies with the same sectoring order